# Mensagem quando excede tamanho de FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando colocar uma mensagem para quando exceder o tamanho do arquivo no FileUpload, já arrumei dentro do web config, porém sempre me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Tamanho máximo de solicitação excedido.

Vi esse exemplo na internet, tentei adaptá-lo pro meu código porém continua aparecendo o erro acima:

```html
<script type ="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('<%= Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {

                //because this is single file upload I use only first index
                var f = this.files[0]

                //here I CHECK if the FILE SIZE is bigger than 8 MB (numbers below are in bytes)
                if (f.size > 8388608 || f.fileSize > 8388608) {
                    //show an alert to the user
                    alert("Allowed file size exceeded. (Max. 8 MB)")

                    //reset file upload control
                    this.value = null;
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Já vi vários exemplos na internet, já tentei de várias formas, pesquisei aqui no fórum e em outros na internet, porém nenhum exemplo está ocorrendo a mensagem de que o tamanho foi excedido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade este exemplo funcionou, estava faltando apenas colocar o # aqui: $('#<%= Anexo.ClientID %>') e deu certo.